# duplicate actions in android application when going to home screen

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment

**Intro:**
My client require some components across the application like `navigationDrawer`, `toolbar`. So I have a `MainActivity` having two `toolbar`(top/bottom) and two navigation drawer(left/right). All other screens consist of `fragments` that I change in `MainActivity`. I have a little problem that is some of the action are being duplicated.
**Cases:**
 In some `fragments` when user perform an action i.e.
**1:** User press "Add To Cart" `button` and press home `button` that is in `toolbar` Bottom, the code of "Add To Cart" `button` run twice (once clicking button, once going to home screen) so my item is being added to cart twice.
**2:** In another fragment I have "apply coupon" `checkbox` when user check that `checkbox` an `AlertDialog` appear and when user go to home screen the `AlertDialog` again appear in the home screen.

I'm simply recreating the main activity on home button press with `recreate();`

I check the code but can't understand why those actions duplicate. If someone faced the same or a bit similar problem please guide me how to tackle that. Any help would be appreciated.

**If I need to show code tell me which part?**

**Edit**:
inside `onCreateView` of fragment Cart Detail

```
useCoupon.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    createAndShowCustomAlertDialog();
                }
            }
        });
```

Sequence of this code is Main Activity(Main Fragment)=>Product Frag=>Cart Detail Frag.

**Edit 2**: MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.utils = new Utils(this);
        utils.changeLanguage("en");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initViews();
        this.context = this;
        setupToolbar(this);
        utils.switchFragment(new MainFrag());
        setOnClickListener();

        initRightMenuData();
        initLeftMenuData();

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(headerListLeft, hashMapLeft,
                false, loggedInIconList);
        listViewExpLeft.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        if (isLoggedIn()) {
            listAdapterRight = new ExpandableListAdapterRight(headerListRight, hashMapRight,
                    loggedInIconList);
        } else {
            listAdapterRight = new ExpandableListAdapterRight(headerListRight, hashMapRight,
                    NotLoggedInIconList);
        }
        listViewExpRight.setAdapter(listAdapterRight);

        enableSingleSelection();
        setExpandableListViewClickListener();
        setExpandableListViewChildClickListener();

    }

    private void setOnClickListener() {
        myAccountTV.setOnClickListener(this);
        checkoutTV.setOnClickListener(this);
        discountTV.setOnClickListener(this);
        homeTV.setOnClickListener(this);
        searchIcon.setOnClickListener(this);
        cartLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void setExpandableListViewClickListener() {
        listViewExpRight.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,
                                        long id) {

                utils.printLog("GroupClicked", " Id = " + id);
                int childCount = parent.getExpandableListAdapter().getChildrenCount(groupPosition);
                if (!isLoggedIn()) {
                    if (childCount < 1) {
                        if (groupPosition == 0) {
                            utils.switchFragment(new FragLogin());
                        } else if (groupPosition == 1) {
                            utils.switchFragment(new FragRegister());
                        } else if (groupPosition == 2) {
                            utils.switchFragment(new FragContactUs());
                        } else {
                            recreate();
                        }
                        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (childCount < 1) {
                        changeFragment(103 + groupPosition);
                        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

        listViewExpLeft.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {

                int childCount = parent.getExpandableListAdapter().getChildrenCount(groupPosition);

                if (childCount < 1) {
                    MenuCategory textChild = (MenuCategory) parent.getExpandableListAdapter()
                            .getGroup(groupPosition);
                    moveToProductFragment(textChild.getMenuCategoryId());
                    utils.printLog("InsideChildClick", "" + textChild.getMenuCategoryId());

                }

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void setExpandableListViewChildClickListener() {
        listViewExpLeft.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,
                                        int childPosition, long id) {

                MenuSubCategory subCategory = (MenuSubCategory) parent.getExpandableListAdapter()
                        .getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

                moveToProductFragment(subCategory.getMenuSubCategoryId());
                utils.printLog("InsideChildClick", "" + subCategory.getMenuSubCategoryId());

                return true;
            }
        });
        listViewExpRight.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                String str = parent.getExpandableListAdapter().getGroup(groupPosition).toString();
                UserSubMenu userSubMenu = (UserSubMenu) parent.getExpandableListAdapter()
                        .getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
                if (str.contains("Information") || str.contains("معلومات")) {
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("id", userSubMenu.getUserSubMenuCode());
                    utils.switchFragment(new FragShowText(), bundle);
                } else if (str.contains("اللغة") || str.contains("Language")) {

                    recreate();
                } else if (str.contains("دقة") || str.contains("Currency")) {
                    makeDefaultCurrencyCall(userSubMenu.getUserSubMenuCode());
                }
                utils.printLog("InsideChildClick", "" + userSubMenu.getUserSubMenuCode());
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void setupToolbar(Context context) {

        ViewCompat.setLayoutDirection(appbarBottom, ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
        ViewCompat.setLayoutDirection(appbarTop, ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);

        String imgPath = Preferences
                .getSharedPreferenceString(appContext, LOGO_KEY, DEFAULT_STRING_VAL);
        utils.printLog("Product Image = " + imgPath);
        if (!imgPath.isEmpty()) {
            Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imgPath)
                    .into(logoIcon);
        }
        logoIcon.setOnClickListener(this);

        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
        actionbarToggle();
        drawer.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        drawerIconLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                } else {
                    drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                    drawerIconLeft.setScaleX(1);
                    drawerIconLeft.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black);
                }
            }
        });
        drawerIconRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
                    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
                } else {
                    drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void initViews() {
        drawerIconLeft = findViewById(R.id.drawer_icon_left);
        drawerIconRight = findViewById(R.id.drawer_icon_right);
        logoIcon = findViewById(R.id.logo_icon);
        searchIcon = findViewById(R.id.search_icon);
        cartLayout = findViewById(R.id.cart_layout);
        counterTV = findViewById(R.id.actionbar_notification_tv);

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        listViewExpLeft = findViewById(R.id.expandable_lv_left);
        listViewExpRight = findViewById(R.id.expandable_lv_right);

        appbarBottom = findViewById(R.id.appbar_bottom);
        appbarTop = findViewById(R.id.appbar_top);
        myAccountTV = findViewById(R.id.my_account_tv);
        discountTV = findViewById(R.id.disc_tv);
        checkoutTV = findViewById(R.id.checkout_tv);
        homeTV = findViewById(R.id.home_tv);

        searchView = findViewById(R.id.search_view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    private void initRightMenuData() {
        headerListRight = new ArrayList<>();
        hashMapRight = new HashMap<>();

        String[] notLoggedInMenu = {findStringByName("login_text"),
                findStringByName("action_register_text"),
                findStringByName("contact_us_text")};
        String[] loggedInMenu = {findStringByName("account"), findStringByName("edit_account_text"),
                findStringByName("action_change_pass_text"),
                findStringByName("order_history_text"),
                findStringByName("logout"), findStringByName("contact_us_text")};

        List<UserSubMenu> userSubMenusList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (isLoggedIn()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < loggedInMenu.length; i++) {
                headerListRight.add(loggedInMenu[i]);
                hashMapRight.put(headerListRight.get(i), userSubMenusList);
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < notLoggedInMenu.length; i++) {
                headerListRight.add(notLoggedInMenu[i]);
                hashMapRight.put(headerListRight.get(i), userSubMenusList);

            }
        }
        String responseStr = "";
        if (getIntent().hasExtra(KEY_EXTRA)) {
            responseStr = getIntent().getStringExtra(KEY_EXTRA);
            utils.printLog("ResponseInInitData", responseStr);
            try {
                JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(responseStr);
                boolean success = responseObject.optBoolean("success");
                if (success) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject homeObject = responseObject.getJSONObject("home");
                        JSONArray slideshow = homeObject.optJSONArray("slideshow");
                        AppConstants.setSlideshowExtra(slideshow.toString());
                        JSONArray menuRight = homeObject.optJSONArray("usermenu");

                        for (int z = 0; z < menuRight.length(); z++) {
                            List<UserSubMenu> userSubMenuList = new ArrayList<>();
                            JSONObject object = menuRight.getJSONObject(z);
                            headerListRight.add(object.optString("name"));
                            JSONArray childArray = object.optJSONArray("children");

                            for (int y = 0; y < childArray.length(); y++) {
                                JSONObject obj = childArray.optJSONObject(y);
                                userSubMenuList.add(new UserSubMenu(obj.optString("code"),
                                        obj.optString("title"), obj.optString("symbol_left"),
                                        obj.optString("symbol_right")));
                            }
                            hashMapRight.put(headerListRight.get(headerListRight.size() - 1), userSubMenuList);
                            utils.printLog("AfterHashMap", "" + hashMapRight.size());
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    utils.showErrorDialog("Error Getting Data From Server");
                    utils.printLog("SuccessFalse", "Within getCategories");
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                utils.printLog("JSONObjEx_MainAct", responseStr);
            }
        } else {
            utils.printLog("ResponseExMainActivity", responseStr);
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Activity cannot find  extras " + KEY_EXTRA);
        }

    }

    private void initLeftMenuData() {
        headerListLeft = new ArrayList<>();
        hashMapLeft = new HashMap<>();

        String responseStr = "";
        if (getIntent().hasExtra(KEY_EXTRA)) {
            responseStr = getIntent().getStringExtra(KEY_EXTRA);
            utils.printLog("ResponseInMainActivity", responseStr);
            try {
                JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(responseStr);
                utils.printLog("JSON_Response", "" + responseObject);
                boolean success = responseObject.optBoolean("success");
                if (success) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject homeObject = responseObject.getJSONObject("home");

                        JSONArray menuCategories = homeObject.optJSONArray("categoryMenu");
                        utils.printLog("Categories", menuCategories.toString());
                        for (int i = 0; i < menuCategories.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject menuCategoryObj = menuCategories.getJSONObject(i);
                            JSONArray menuSubCategoryArray = menuCategoryObj.optJSONArray(
                                    "children");

                            List<MenuSubCategory> childMenuList = new ArrayList<>();
                            for (int j = 0; j < menuSubCategoryArray.length(); j++) {
                                JSONObject menuSubCategoryObj = menuSubCategoryArray.getJSONObject(j);
                                MenuSubCategory menuSubCategory = new MenuSubCategory(
                                        menuSubCategoryObj.optString("child_id"),
                                        menuSubCategoryObj.optString("name"));
                                childMenuList.add(menuSubCategory);
                            }
                            MenuCategory menuCategory = new MenuCategory(menuCategoryObj.optString(
                                    "category_id"), menuCategoryObj.optString("name"),
                                    menuCategoryObj.optString("icon"), childMenuList);
                            headerListLeft.add(menuCategory);
                            hashMapLeft.put(headerListLeft.get(i), menuCategory.getMenuSubCategory());
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } 
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            utils.printLog("ResponseExMainActivity", responseStr);
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Activity cannot find  extras " + KEY_EXTRA);
        }
    }

    private void actionbarToggle() {
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(MainActivity.this, drawer,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {

            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                drawerIconLeft.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_list_black);
                drawerIconLeft.setScaleX(-1);
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();

        if (id == R.id.logo_icon) {
            recreate();
        } else if (id == R.id.my_account_tv) {
            utils.switchFragment(new Dashboard());
        } else if (id == R.id.disc_tv) {
            utils.printLog("From = Main Act");
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("from", "mainActivity");
            utils.switchFragment(new FragProduct(), bundle);

        } else if (id == R.id.checkout_tv) {
            if (isLoggedIn()) {
                utils.switchFragment(new FragCheckout());
            } else {
                AlertDialog alertDialog = utils.showAlertDialogReturnDialog("Continue As",
                        "Select the appropriate option");
                alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE,
                        "As Guest", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                utils.switchFragment(new FragCheckout());
                            }
                        });
                alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE,
                        "Login", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                utils.switchFragment(new FragLogin());
                            }
                        });
                alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEUTRAL,
                        "Register", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                utils.switchFragment(new FragRegister());
                            }
                        });
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        } else if (id == R.id.home_tv) {
            recreate();
        } else if (id == R.id.search_icon) {
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(context, SearchActivity.class), SEARCH_REQUEST_CODE);
        } else if (id == R.id.cart_layout) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("midFix", "cartProducts");
            utils.switchFragment(new FragCartDetail(), bundle);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == SEARCH_REQUEST_CODE || requestCode == CURRENCY_REQUEST_CODE
                || requestCode == LANGUAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (data != null) {
                String responseStr = data.getStringExtra("result");
                utils.printLog("ResponseIs = " + responseStr);

                if (responseStr != null) {
                    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                        JSONObject response;
                        if (!isJSONString(responseStr)) {
                            try {
                                response = new JSONObject(responseStr);
                                if (requestCode == CURRENCY_REQUEST_CODE) {
                                    JSONObject object = response.optJSONObject("currency");
                                    Preferences.setSharedPreferenceString(appContext
                                            , CURRENCY_SYMBOL_KEY
                                            , object.optString("symbol_left")
                                                    + object.optString("symbol_right")
                                    );
                                    recreate();
                                } else if (requestCode == LANGUAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
                                    JSONObject object = response.optJSONObject("language");
                                    Preferences.setSharedPreferenceString(appContext
                                            , LANGUAGE_KEY
                                            , object.optString("code")
                                    );
                                    recreate();
                                }

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (requestCode == SEARCH_REQUEST_CODE) {
                                if (responseStr.isEmpty())
                                    return;
                                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                bundle.putString("id", responseStr);
                                bundle.putString("from", "fromSearch");
                                utils.switchFragment(new FragProduct(), bundle);
                            } else {
                                utils.showAlertDialog("Alert", responseStr);
                            }
                        }
                    } else if (resultCode == FORCED_CANCEL) {
                        utils.printLog("WithinSearchResult", "If Success False" + responseStr);
                    } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                        utils.printLog("WithinSearchResult", "Result Cancel" + responseStr);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

MainFragment

```
public class MainFrag extends MyBaseFragment {

    public MainFrag() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_main, container, false);
        initUtils();
        initViews(view);
        utils.setupSlider(mPager, indicator, pb, true, true);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager =
                new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()
                        , LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        List<String> keysList = prepareData();
        if (keysList.size() > 0 && !keysList.isEmpty()) {
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MainFragmentAdapter(keysList));
        }

        return view;
    }

    private void initViews(View view) {
        mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.parent_recycler_view);
        mPager = view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        indicator = view.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        pb = view.findViewById(R.id.loading);
    }

    private List<String> prepareData() {
        String responseStr = getHomeExtra();
        List<String> keysStr = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(responseStr);
            utils.printLog("JSON_Response", "" + responseObject);
            boolean success = responseObject.optBoolean("success");
            if (success) {
                JSONObject homeObject = responseObject.optJSONObject("home");
                JSONObject modules = homeObject.optJSONObject("modules");

                Iterator<?> keys = modules.keys();
                while (keys.hasNext()) {
                    String key = (String) keys.next();
                    keysStr.add(key);
                    utils.printLog("KeyStr", key);
                }
                utils.printLog("ModuleSize", modules.toString());
            } else {
                utils.printLog("SuccessFalse", "Within getCategories");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            utils.printLog("JSONEx_MainFragTest", responseStr);
        }
        return keysStr;
    }
}
```

I removed global variables and some method because of length.

Comment: you can post the main activity and home fragment

Comment: These are too lengthy is there a way to show code that would look short? Otherwise I would paste them here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use recreate() method here, as it forces the activity to reload everything. Just use intent to call your Home activity, that should solve this issue.

Comment: As of I know `recreate();` reload everything that is inside that activity But not those things that would be part of that activity later on.

Comment: I mean to say I have `MainFargment` on `MainActivity` by default, recreate() would affect it not the other `fragments` that are not attached to `mainActivity` yet

Comment: can you provide the code block where you're having problem?

Answer (score 0):

From the hint of @Akash Khatri I use to switch to `mainFragment` and its fine now. Actually @Akash is right `recreate();` everything at present But as I was setting main fragment in OnCreate of MainActivity. So, It was hard to notice that Android first recreate everything and in no time It call the main Fragment.

I do not using Intent to start the same activity again Because Switching fragment is more convenient. And also I pass Some extras to it that I will loose  With new Intent.